# What did major figures in the leave camp say would be the result of Brexit on immigration?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, brexit

What did major figures (individuals or organisations) from the leave camp of the Brexit referendum say would be the result of leaving the EU would be on immigration?

Ideally answers should indicate what was said, whether the statement was explicit or merely implied, who or what organisation said it, and how much of a role that person or organisation played in the leave camp.

Comment: One minor problem is that Calais will move the ["jungle" to Dover](http://www.express.co.uk/news/world/683204/calais-jungle-brexit-dover-referendum), since it was supposed to be the border and no Calais, the Treaty will have no more validity when UK will leave EU.

Comment: @GautierC Apparently this treaty will be unaffected by the Brexit vote?  https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/jun/25/french-border-deal-wont-be-affected-by-brexit-paris

Comment: @Dave On a french side, trust me, it will be affected , or they will be some social movement ^^"

Comment: @GautierC until such time as that happens, we have to take the politician's (French ministers) stated intents as being valid though - and at this point, that treaty will remain in place despite the vote.  That could of course change in the coming weeks/months/years.

Comment: @Dave Just sayin', in my country, the election are the next year, so the government will not do more than it did to get the population more angry than they currently are. Just so you can understand. The actual governement will certainly withdraw what it said because they want to win the election, it did it before. So yeah, I agree, but with the climat in France, it is a high possibility !

Comment: Yeah. Did they say anything about the border of Northern Ireland and Eire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fox on 29th May 2016 said it was "entirely possible" to meet the pledge to reduce immigration to tens of thousands. "But only in my view if we left the European Union," he added. [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/wires/pa/article-3614928/Liam-Fox-Brexit-help-cut-immigration-tens-thousands.html) (Fox was a well know Tory supporter of Leave)

Gove and Johnson said migrants will be barred from entering Britain after a Brexit unless they can speak good English and have the right skills for a job, and proposed a points-based system. [Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/05/31/eu-referendum-boris-and-gove-pledge-tough-new-immigration-system/) (Gove and Johnson were seen as the leaders of the Leave campaign).

Hoey said that Brexit would decrease the numbers of low-pay immigrants from EU countries [the heat](https://heatst.com/world/kate-hoey-the-left-wing-case-for-brexit/). Hoey is a notable Labour Brexit campaigner.

In general all Brexit supporters said there would be a decrease in immigration following Brexit. It is implied that there may be some greater immigration from non-EU countries under a points system.